# node-cache taking to long to get large data on aws elasticbeanstalk

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

im using [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache) to cache a large set of data and when im trying to get access to this data it's taking too long. Any suggestions on what i should do to make the get cache data load faster.

Comment: How large is your 'large set of data'? Node-cache doesn't seem like a natural choice for large data set. Depending on your use case such as number of clients reading/writing you should probably consider different caching option such as AWS ElasticCache for Redis.

Comment: the data set is an array of 750 objects. and i will look into AWS ElasticCache for Redis thanks.